# Evaluate $\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}Ax^2e^{-\lambda^2x^2}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, normal-distribution

> Let's assume $A>0$ and $\lambda\neq0$. Evaluate $\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}Ax^2e^{-\lambda^2x^2}dx$. (Hint: Use the properties of the density function of the normal distribution)

---

Let $Y$ obey $\mathcal{N}(0,\frac{1}{2})$. We know that

$
\begin{align*}
&\mathbb{V}(Y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)^2}}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2}}dx=\frac{1}{2}\\
&\implies \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2e^{-x^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi} }{2}.
\end{align*}$

Because of the symmetry around $0$ we know that $ \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}x^2e^{-x^2}dx=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{\pi}$.

Hence,

\begin{align*}
\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}Ax^2e^{-\lambda^2x^2}dx=\frac{A}{\lambda^3}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}z^2e^{-z^2}dz=\frac{A\sqrt{\pi}}{\lambda^3 4}.
\end{align*}

Is this correct? I am not sure because the sample solution says $\frac{A\sqrt{\pi}}{\lambda^3}$.

Comment: Yes, your result is correct. (Maybe it begs the question of how you compute the variance of $Y\sim {\cal N}(0, 1/2)$ or $Y\sim {\cal N}(0, 1)$ in the first place, but the question sounds like it assumes that's known.)